# Want to install zlib to install pillow in python 3.8.10 (32-bit)

Tags: python, zlib, python-3.8, python-zlib

I want to install pillow in python 3.8.10 in my windows 7 32 bit.
But when I write "pip install pillow" it gives:

"The header and library files could not be found for zlib, a required dependency when compiling pillow from sources"

I tried "pip show zlib" that gives:

"Package(s) not found:zlib"

So how to I install this zlib?? and then install pillow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try one of [these](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/4242) fixes.

Comment: Thank UU for sharing this. I am able to download pillow=9.5.0 :) However I still want to know, is downloading zlib possible in my system or not? If yes, then how?

Comment: If you want to use zlib with python: python's standard library already includes the zlib module, so you don't need to install it separately.

Comment: I know but it shows package not found. That's why a ask

Comment: same for me, still works with python...

maybe try: `pip uninstall zlib && pip install zlib`